# Android Exception handling best practice

Tags: android, exception, generics

I have some more and less big android projects. There are now really a lot of `try/catch` phrases in my code. Is there best practice for handling these?
Sometimes there would be a `Toast` necessary, sometimes an `AlertDialog` and sometimes even nothing.
Most of my exception handling happens in `asynctasks` with web requests and JSON parsing.

At the moment I'm handling it this way:
I wrote a `ErrorCase` class which I'm giving the `context`, `the class` where it happened, and the `error String`.

So a `try/catch` looks like this

```
 try
 {
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    //some more code

    if (statusLine.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK)
    {
        new ErrorCase(c, getClass().getSimpleName(), c.getString(R.string.errorHTTP));
    }
 }
 catch (ClientProtocolException e)
 {
    new ErrorCase(c, getClass().getSimpleName(), c.getString(R.string.errorClientProtocolException));
 }
 catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
 {
    new ErrorCase(c, getClass().getSimpleName(), c.getString(R.string.errorUnsupportedEncodingException));
 }
 catch (IOException e)
 {
    new ErrorCase(c, getClass().getSimpleName(), c.getString(R.string.errorIOException));
 }
```

and the `ErrorCase` class like this

```
public class ErrorCase
{
    private Context main;
    private String className;
    private String reason;

    public ErrorCase(Context main, String className, String reason)
    {
        this.main = main;
        this.className = className;
        this.reason = reason;

        new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                showToast();
            }
        };
    }

    private void showToast()
    {
        Toast.makeText(main, className.length() + "" + className.charAt(0) + className.charAt(className.length() - 1) + " " + reason, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ((Activity) main).finish();
    }}
```

I'm open to any practical generic suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Before going to write exception handling class, one must understand `Checked vs Unchecked Exceptions`. This [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/checked-vs-unchecked-exceptions-in-java/) explains about it.

Now, checkout the code explained [here](https://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/how-to-avoid-force-close-error-in-android/). `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` is
interface for handlers invoked when a Thread abruptly terminates due to an uncaught exception - [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html).

Here is another [link](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/04/java-exception-handling-best-practices/) that explains about exceptions nicely.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm fine with uncaught exceptions, for now I'm just looking if there's a more beautiful solution for my caught exceptions.